# Azure pipeline output error CS0117: 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'XXXid' (Xamarin Android)

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure pipeline to build a Xamarin Android project. This project has file structure like this :

```
--Root --|- MyApp.Core ----------|- MyApp.Core ----- MyApp.Core.csproj
         |- azure-pipelines.yml  |- MyApp.Droid ---- MyApp.Droid.csproj
                                 |- MyApp.Core.sln
```

Problem is I can build successfully locally, but always fail with pipeline.
Here is the error log from pipeline console:

```
  Activities/LauncherActivity.cs(30,56): error CS0117: 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'startDiDi' [/Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/MyApp.Core/MyApp.Droid/MyApp.Droid.csproj]
  Activities/LauncherActivity.cs(32,56): error CS0117: 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'startUber' [/Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/MyApp.Core/MyApp.Droid/MyApp.Droid.csproj]
```

Where ***startDiDi*** and ***startUber*** is the button id in xml.

Here is my **azure-pipelines.yml** file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/MyApp.Core.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/MyApp.Droid.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Here is the **xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
  >
    <Space
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>

    <Button android:id="@+id/startDiDi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DiDi"
            android:height="130dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    />

    <Space
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>

    <Button android:id="@+id/startUber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Uber"
            android:height="130dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="40dp"
    />

    <Space
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
    </Space>
  </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hopefully someone can point me a direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show your xml file?and you could try to delete the content of `Resource.Designer.cs `and rebuild it.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Hi thanks for reply, I have attached my xml file, and I did try delete content of Resource.Designer.cs and rebuild it, but no luck :(